# Is there a way I can create an input/output calculator using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and want to code something that will generate a series of data for a given function. For example, if the user types in a rule such as `y = x + 2`, i would like to have a table that would show the value of `y` when `x` equals `1` - `10`.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Take a look at the `Function` constructor.

Comment: @Barmar: God no, no need for that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The alternative is writing an equation parser of your own, isn't it? Not recommended for a newbie. You could also use `eval`, which is effectively the same as creating a function.

Comment: @Barmar: Amusingly, I was thinking something along the lines of "`Function` constructor? May as well use `eval`!" Yes, writing (or better use, [*using*](http://esprima.org/)) a parser would be the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use eval: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

```
// Remove variable "y = " to get just the expression
var userExpression = str.replace(/y\s*=\s*/i, document.getElementById('textbox_id').value);

for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    var x = i;
    var y = eval(userExpression);
    console.log("x: " + x + "\t y: " + y);
}
```

***EDIT***

This is if you were running it on the same page within the same browser. If you planned on storing the evaluation expression and then evaluating it later
for other users and browser sessions this can easily open up security exploits. So you would need to be careful on how you plan on using this.

Comment: So long as you only ever use a user's input for *them*, and never for anyone else.

Comment: Yes, you should not be storing the user's input and then running the eval for other users since that's an exploitable security leak.